# can you swap any 2 food tokens for an activated ability?

Tags: wingspan

When you're playing birds you can swap two food tokens for any other food token but does that also apply to activated abilities? eg.

[image]

Could I play two worm tokens in lieu of a fish token?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [rulebook](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules6/Wingspan%20-%20rules.pdf), page 6:

> When playing birds, you may spend any 2 food tokens as if
> they are any 1 food token. This exchange cannot be used during
> other parts of the game.

So the answer is no - you can only substitute food tokens when playing birds, not when using other abilities.